# Difference in folder quantity between get-childitem results and Windows file properties

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, powershell

When I right clicked on specific folder for its properties, it listed 3181 folders on the General tab.

I was using the powershell command get-childitem -recurse to get a list of all the directories within the same folder.  I figured a .count would result in the same amount, but it didn't.  It returned 3175 items.

The actual powershell commands I used were:

```
$list = gci c:\somefolder -recurse | where {$_.psiscontainer -eq $true}
$list.count
```

Anyone know why the difference in numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suspect its not showing hidden folders.  Add `-Force -Recurse` and I think you will get the proper result.

Comment: Good call.  I should have thought of that.  Adding -force made it match up.  Thanks for the answer.